# how to fix resource not found error in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

This error shows up when I was writing my code. error:

Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/edit_message').

The code is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show us your strings XXL?

Answer (score 1):

That is easy.Just add a item like this in your `res/values/strings.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="edit_message">YOUR MESSAGE TEXT</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default string resources folder android generates called strings, did you write the XML manually or it is a generated code?
if manually,  try to fix it:

```
android:hint="@strings/edit_message"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set hint on edittext like this from programmatically if resource is not found in your application:

```
editMessage.setHint("hint message"):
```

or you can simply 
**Call setHint() on the EditText.**

Refer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28int%29